# One Sample Binomial or 2 Sample Binomial

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

So there is this one question, but I do not know what to use. (I believe it is 1 sample, can you plz tell me if I am right and wrong, and why?)

The company Pepsi does a test to see what people like better Pepsi or Coke. They were able to find that 10/19 people prefer Pepsi while 9/19 prefer Coke. Test the trup proportion of people liking Pespi is .5? I belive it is one sample with

q=.5
q is not equal .5

Please let me know if I am correct or not?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I think you shold use the one-sample binomial test with $H_0:p=0.5$ and $H_1:p\neq 0.5$

The two-sample test is not applicable here because you only have one group of data, whereas the two-sample test is often used when you want to compare two groups of paired or unpaired data.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Thats's, what I thought but was 2nd guessing